# Scroll Bar is not moving but not the contents

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, frontend

***Problem description:***

I am totally new to the GUI development on Tkinter. Moving to the problem, i have main window and it is divided into two different frames top and bottom frame. I want to move the top frame alone when I am moving the  horizontal scroll bar. the scroll bar is moving but contents are not moving with it.

***What i have tried:***
the procedure followed: main window --> top frame (on main window) --> canvas (on top frame) -->  scrollable frame (on canvas) --> 10 different frames

scroll bar is connected to top frame (set to canvas xview).

though scroll bar set, again i have add the following code ( code is given at the end)

sizes:

top frame - width = 5000, height = 550,
canvas  -w = 50000 , h = 5500 ,  (scroll region - (0,0,50000,5500)),
scrollable frame - not defined,
10 diff frame - w = 500 , h = 400 ( single frame size),

bottom frame size - w = 400, height = 400

somebody please help. I am breaking my head with this for 1 week.

***Code:***

```
from tkinter import * 
from tkinter.ttk import *

top1 = tk.Tk()  
top1.title("Output window")
  
fram1 =tk.Frame(top1,width=5000,height=550,bg = 'khaki1',relief=SUNKEN) 
canvas = Canvas (fram1,width=50000,height=5500,bg = 'sky blue',scrollregion(0,0,50000,5500))

fram2 =ttk.Frame(top1,width=400,height=400,relief=SUNKEN) 
 
scroll_bar_v = tk.Scrollbar(top1,orient='vertical') 
scroll_bar_v.pack( side = RIGHT, fill = Y ) 

scroll_bar_h = Scrollbar(fram1,orient='horizontal') 
scroll_bar_h.config(command = canvas.xview)
scroll_bar_h.pack( side = BOTTOM, fill = X )

left1= ttk.Frame(fram2, borderwidth=2, height = 400,width = 500,relief="sunken")
left2= ttk.Frame(fram2, borderwidth=2, height = 400,width = 500,relief="sunken")
left3= ttk.Frame(fram2, borderwidth=2, height = 400,width = 500,relief="sunken")


left1.pack(side = 'left',padx=10, pady=10)
left2.pack(side = 'left',padx=10, pady=10)
left3.pack(side = 'left',padx=10, pady=10)


scrollable_frame = tk.Frame(canvas, bg = 'khaki1')
scrollable_frame.pack(side = 'top',padx = 10,pady = 10)


for i in range(10):

    left = tk.Frame(scrollable_frame, borderwidth=2, height = 400,width = 500,relief="sunken") # fram1 to canvas
    left. pack(side = 'left',padx=10, pady=10)
    l1 = tk.Label (left,text = i,font = ('Arial',20,'bold')).place(x = 50, y =30)

canvas.configure(xscrollcommand= scroll_bar_h.set,scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all")) 
canvas.pack(fill = 'both')     
 

fram1.pack(side = 'top')
fram2.pack(side = 'bottom')

top1.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Did you update `scrollregion` after adding the 10 frames?

Comment: No, I guess. can you please tell me how to do it?

Comment: You should not call `scrollable_frame.pack(...)`.  Use `canvas.create_window(0, 0, window=scrollable_frame, anchor='nw')` instead.  Also you need to call `scrollable_frame.update()` after inserting the 10 frames (ie after the for loop) and before `canvas.configure(...)`.

Comment: hey, thats helped a lot. it is working good now. thanks a lot